# `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` called on delegate that doesn't implement it

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SomeClassNameController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1805f1f0'

Unless I've misunderstood the documentation, this shouldn't be possible. If `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` isn't implemented in the delegate it should use whatever value that is stored in `sectionHeaderHeight`. Under no circumstances should it call `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` on a delegate that doesn't implement it.

Is this correct or did I in fact misunderstand the documentation?

**EDIT:** Stack trace as requested.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x30443e83 __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3aadf6c7 _objc_exception_throw + 39
2   CoreFoundation                      0x304477b7 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 203
3   CoreFoundation                      0x30445f4d ___forwarding___ + 353
4   CoreFoundation                      0x30394dc8 __CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5   UIKit                               0x32cabfff -[UISectionRowData heightForHeaderInSection:canGuess:] + 123
6   UIKit                               0x32cabf2b -[UITableViewRowData rectForHeaderInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 391
7   UIKit                               0x32dc83b3 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForExistingHeadersAndFooters] + 1603
8   UIKit                               0x32dc37db -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 187
9   UIKit                               0x32dc328b -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 1363
10  UIKit                               0x32d9b397 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 8019
11  appname                             0x000704a9 -[SomeClassNameView layoutSubviews] (SomeClassNameView.m:47)
12  UIKit                               0x32bc8353 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 347
13  QuartzCore                          0x3284e943 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 143
14  QuartzCore                          0x3284a167 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 351
15  QuartzCore                          0x32849ff9 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 17
16  QuartzCore                          0x32849a0d CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 229
17  QuartzCore                          0x3284981f CA::Transaction::commit() + 315
18  QuartzCore                          0x3284354d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 57
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3040ef69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21
20  CoreFoundation                      0x3040c8f7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 287
21  CoreFoundation                      0x3040cc43 __CFRunLoopRun + 739
22  CoreFoundation                      0x30377471 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
23  CoreFoundation                      0x30377253 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
24  GraphicsServices                    0x350782eb _GSEventRunModal + 139
25  UIKit                               0x32c2c845 _UIApplicationMain + 1137
26  appname                             0x00386767 main (main.m:32)
27  appname                             0x00020e48 start + 40
```

Comment: For testing purposes, if you implement it... does it get called?

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Looks like the delegate is pointing at the wrong thing or garbage.

Comment: @Zaph, this is a proper delegate. It just doesn't implement this method.

Comment: @Wain, yes, I edited my question to include it.

Comment: @Merlevede, it is from a crash log, so I don't actually know how to reproduce it. Not yet anyway.

Comment: But is the delegate valid at that point? Is it declared _weak_?

Comment: @Zaph, otherwise I would get bad access, so yes it is valid.

Comment: Assuming that the block of memory has not been returned to the system--very unlikely-- you will usually not get a bad address, more likely a selector not implemented because the address not points to a different object. Note in the error message the object is reported as: `SomeClassName`. Make the delegate `_-weak` and when the object is deallocated it will be set to nil, there will not be a crash but still an error to e fixed. Unless you can come up with a better possibility it looks like the message is being sent to another object or reallocated and partially reused object memory.

Comment: The scenario that Apple's `UITableView` class is that badly flawed is a non-starter, the iPhone could not run. It s an error in your program, take that mindset and you should be able to find the error.

Comment: @Zaph: I read it as Erik B not wanting to publish his actual class name, so he replaced it with “SomeClassName”. I wouldn't assume that it's a different/wrong class. (Also, note that “SomeClassName” also appears in the stack trace, for a receiver of `layoutSubviews`.)

Comment: Erik, can you share some code? Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Peter Hosey's assumption is correct. Due to NDA I am not allowed to share the code. Therefore, I anonymized the stack trace and the error message. I was a bit quick in doing so; I used `SomeClassName` for two different classes (that were similarly named), but I've changed `SomeClassName` to `SomeClassNameController` and `SomeClassNameView` to make it clear that there is a view and a controller involved. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the crash? If yes, can you tell us what kind of an instance the selector is sent to? E.g. in LLDB: `po [0x1805f1f0 class]`

Comment: Can you give us the address of whatever instance is the delegate before you assign it as delegate? Also, an updated "unrecognized selector sent to instance" console out that includes the address please

Comment: Sanity check: Does `p [0x1805f1f0 respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:)]` indicate that that method is believed to exist? Does your project engage in weird Objective-C runtime wizardry, particularly after the table view's delegate is set?

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon If I could reproduce it I would try it. All I have is a handful of crash reports collected from users. I played around with the view for a while, but it didn't crash for me. We are doing some runtime wizardry in the project, but since I cannot reproduce the crash it is hard for me to verify if the runtime wizardry is the cause of this. I have a lot of other issues to work on, but if I find some time I will do a second investigation based on your input. Thanks.

Comment: @ErikB I only noticed that you weren't able to reproduce it after the edit window on my comment had expired. Runtime wizardry is all well and good—I do it all the time—but given that you're having this problem, I'd be suspicious of any being done with SomeClassNameControllers or their superclasses, particularly `object_setClass()` or perhaps `class_addMethod()` or `class_replaceMethod()`.

Comment: Just to let you know in case you didn't see them, Zac has posted a couple of further comments on his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21690791/30461

Answer (score 4):

Any chance you're using the Apptimize framework for A/B testing? Introducing it into my project causes it to cause the UITableView delegate responding checks to stop working, and makes the UITableView issue you're describing happen. If I remove the framework, it stops happening.

Comment: We do not use Apptimize, but that is interesting. If you could think of why Apptimize would cause this we might find the answer.

Comment: My *only* guess is they are doing something crazy in +load or another override that's messing with regular behavior. Are you using any other libraries? Perhaps doing a binary search could help you figure out which is causing it.

Comment: I spoke with the Apptimize folks. They were swizzling -respondsToSelector: and not handling the fact that the implementation changes in some sub-classes. Perhaps it's similar for you.

Comment: I have the same crush probably caused by Apptimize too

Answer (score 1):

From the docs

```
Special Considerations
Prior to iOS 5.0, table views would automatically resize the heights of headers to 0 for sections where tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: returned a nil view. In iOS 5.0 and later, you must return the actual height for each section header in this method.
```

Is this change causing the issue.

Are you creating the table view from code or xib?
If it is xib , I am sure there is some default value for section header height, but what if you are creating it through code. May be when running in compatibility mode there is some problem with default value of 'sectionHeaderHeight'.

Comment: All crashes are on iOS 7. The app is running in compatibility mode. So I guess it might be a bug in iOS 7's compatibility mode or in iOS 7 in general.

Comment: Also, as @ErikB mentioned in a comment on another answer, he didn't implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

```
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
...
Discussion
The returned object can be a UILabel or UIImageView object, as well as a custom view.
This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Apparently Apple interprets "doesn't work correctly" as "may crash."

Answer (score 0):

I am not the coder but the delegate methods are run all the time using default coding if there is no override. Just that if there is an override, the code in the override gets executed instead of the default.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

In this case the method expects the Tableview instance address and an NSInteger representing the section, an invalid value in one of them will cause the exception.    ...

I would concentrate the debugging effort on the state of the tableview or the section before the exception happens  ....

For that matter I would code the delegate method put a breakpoint and see what gets passed into it.

Comment: Are you sure the delegate methods are implemented by default? Invalid arguments to an implemented method wouldn't cause a “does not respond to selector” exception.

Comment: Maybe we should ask apple, I am sure code gets executed to determine the height of the section, whether its called the same method or not without the user's delegate code so it appears during a trace is something to ask Apple.  .... In any case the best way to start figuring things out is there.

Comment: Regarding delegate methods    - the call to super tells me that the default code for delegate are similarly named, but it really depends on who coded the class.                                         - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

Comment: `viewDidUnload` isn't a delegate method; it's a method declared and implemented by UIViewController and intended for subclasses to override. `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` is declared in a protocol; there is no implementation to override, nor to call up to via `super`.

Comment: You are right, UITableview delegate methods do not have those kinds of calls to super,  The invalid selector refers to a missing   tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:  I'd still code it to figure out whats happening and why it is getting called.  ....  I have an IOS7 app with Tableview using multi section data (I have a dictionary as datasource (embedded array within an array)  - and this does not happen to me). I think it is either data related or some of the codes is being overriden by unmatched parameters - you have to start debugging somewhere.